# React saga lifecycle

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Below is a snippet of my login saga:

```
export function* loginFlow() {
  while (true) {
    const request = yield take(LOGIN_REQUEST);
    const { username, password } = request.data;

    const authResp = yield call(authorize, { username, password });
    if (authResp) {
      yield put({ type: SET_AUTH, newAuthState: true }); // User is logged in (authorized)
      yield put({ type: CHANGE_FORM, newFormState: { username: '', password: '' } }); // Clear form
      forwardTo('/home'); // Go to dashboard page
    }
  }
}
```

This saga is in my LoginContainer. Now everytime I go to the login screen and load the login container, a new saga "process" is spawned, so everytime I revisit the login screen, I have increasingly more and more requests going to my login API when I click the "login" button.

Can I somehow destroy the saga upon component destroy?

EDIT: Here's an attempt to cancel the saga:

```
export function* loginFlow() {
  const request = yield take(LOGIN_REQUEST);
  const { username, password } = request.data;

  const authResp = yield call(authorize, { username, password });
  if (authResp) {
    yield put({ type: SET_AUTH, newAuthState: true }); // User is logged in (authorized)
    yield put({ type: CHANGE_FORM, newFormState: { username: '', password: '' } }); // Clear form
    forwardTo('/home'); // Go to dashboard page
  }
}

export function* watchLogin() {
  // or takeEvery (according to your business logic)
  yield* takeEvery(LOGIN_REQUEST, loginFlow);
}

export function* root() {
  const watchers = [
    yield fork(watchLogin),
  ];

  // Cancel all watchers on location change
  yield take(LOCATION_CHANGE);

  watchers.forEach(function(watcher) {
    console.log("cancelling watcher")
    cancel(watcher)
  });
}

// All sagas to be loaded
export default [
  root,
];
```

I have to click on the login button twice on the initial load, so that the API request is made at all, then I am experiencing the same behaviour as before - the saga doesn't get cancelled and the requests keep adding up.

Here's my component:

```
export class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(newFormState) {
    this.props.dispatch(changeForm(newFormState));
  }

  login(username, password) {
    console.log("dispatching login request")
    this.props.dispatch(loginRequest({ username, password }));
  }

  render() {
    const { formState, currentlySending, error } = this.props;

    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <LoginForm onChange={this.onChange} data={formState} error={error} currentlySending={currentlySending} btnText={messages.btnText} usernameText={messages.usernameText} passwordText={messages.passwordText} onSubmit={this.login} />
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's how I load my sagas (routes.js):

```
export default function createRoutes(store) {
  // create reusable async injectors using getAsyncInjectors factory
  const { injectReducer, injectSagas } = getAsyncInjectors(store);

  return [
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        const importModules = Promise.all([
          System.import('containers/Login/reducer'),
          System.import('containers/Login/sagas'),
          System.import('containers/Login'),
        ]);

        const renderRoute = loadModule(cb);

        importModules.then(([reducer, sagas, component]) => {
          injectReducer('login', reducer.default);
          injectSagas(sagas.default);
          renderRoute(component);
        });

    importModules.catch(errorLoading);
  },
...
```

And here's the forwardTo function that I believe is the one causing problems:

```
function forwardTo(location) {
  browserHistory.push(location);
}
```

If I break before I call this function inside the saga's while loop, the saga gets destroyed automatically and all works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes you can destroy your saga-watchers on **component** destruction, and that would be either by two methods:

1. Add to actions for component mount and unmount, then in your React component's method, `componentWillMount`, dispatch the mounting action and on `componentWillUnmount` dispatch the unmounting action and handle your sagas accordingly.
2. You'd destroy your saga-watchers on **page/container** NOT component destruction, and you just listen on `LOCATION_CHANGE` action (maybe from `react-router-redux` if you use it) rather than `COMPONENT_UNMOUNT` action (*as mentioned in the first method above*)

---

Here you go a sample for applying the *second method* in your saga, also some modification for your `loginFlow` saga generator:

```
import {call, cancel, fork, put, take} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {takeEvery, takeLatest} from 'redux-saga';
import {LOCATION_CHANGE} from 'react-router-redux';
import {
  LOGIN_REQUEST,
  SET_AUTH,
  CHANGE_FORM,
} from './constants';

export function* loginFlow() {
  const request = yield take(LOGIN_REQUEST);
  const { username, password } = request.data;

  const authResp = yield call(authorize, { username, password });
  if (authResp) {

    // User is logged in (authorized)
    yield put({ type: SET_AUTH, newAuthState: true });

    // Clear form
    yield put({ type: CHANGE_FORM, newFormState: {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    } });

    forwardTo('/home'); // Go to dashboard page
  }
}

export function* watchLogin() {
  // or takeEvery (according to your business logic)
  yield* takeLatest(LOGIN_REQUEST, loginFlow);
}

export function* root() {
  const watchers = [
    yield fork(watchLogin),
  ];

  // Cancel all watchers on location change
  yield take(LOCATION_CHANGE);
  watchers.forEach(cancel);
}

// All sagas to be loaded
export default [
  root,
];
```

Now a shown above, we use some of `redux-saga/effects` to **fork** saga watchers on usage of the component/container then use **cancel** to destroy watchers on `LOCATION_CHANGE`.

Also, you need to dispatch you `LOGIN_REQUEST` action on buttonClick in the LoginComponent.

---

Please, ask for clarification if something is not clear.

Read more about task cancellation from `redux-saga` documentation [here](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation.html).

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the original post with my attempt at implementing the above code, I am still experiencing weird behaviour and the saga does not get cancelled.

Comment: I'd ask where do you inject/load your sagas? Also would you write down your React component to investigate improper functionality?

Comment: I've edited the original post with some additional data

Comment: So, as you mentioned the error come from navigating, I suggest moving this logic to the component, so you check on some value in the `props` like `authUser`, if true, route to some where, also try `react-router-redux` in routing.